# chat notification when app is background using firebase

Tags: ios, firebase

I am new to firebase. I am implementing one to one chat application using it, I am able to chat with user when he is online. Now I want to notify the user for receiving a message when his app is in background.

I am RND so many links, but I can't find any related article or answer.

Please help me.

Comment: This is pretty simple and there's sample code right on Firebase's website showing how to receive and process notifications when the app is in the background. [Receive Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive)

Answer (score -1):

when an IOS app is killed it's not present in the memory and you can't keep a service that listen to firebase running in the background you must have some backend code listen to changes in a database node and push a notification to phone when a new message is received.

luckily the new service of firebase "cloud functions" could do the same for you, here is an [example](https://android.jlelse.eu/serverless-notifications-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-685d7c327cd4) of how to use it with android I think it's the same for IOS

### update:

you may look at the server javascript [code](http://you%20need%20to%20look%20at%20the%20server%20code%20https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM/blob/master/server/functions/index.js%20not%20the%20android) to get a hint about how it works, the cloud function will listen to node changes and notify user if needed so you don't need extra code in IOS, the flow will be something like this:

```
db/
  |-notifications
  |-messages
```

when you send message to someone you push the message to it's normal node and also to the notification node

```
db/
  |-notifications
  |\
  | |-[message id]
  |  \-from: [sender id]
  |  \-to: [receiver id]
  |  \-message: [message body]
  |
  |-messages
   \
    |-[sender id]
     \
      |-[receiver id]
       \
        |-[message id]
         \-from: [sender id]
         \-to: [receiver id]
         \-message: [message body]
```

and the cloud function listens to that notification node and perform it's action of sending the notification to phone

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I can't understand that android code. can you please provide any link or any help which is in iOS?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this answer is correct, or really even an answer to the question. The OP asked about *receiving a message when his app is in background* and didn't mention killing an app. It's pretty straight forward and well documented: *When your app is in the background, iOS directs messages with the notification key to the system tray.*

Comment: I thought his problem is sending the notification not receiving it, so that was my answer

Comment: Understood - however, the answer does not address the question at all. The OP as asking about receiving notifications in the background in Swift. I would suggest updating it to answer the question by providing Swift code in the answer (not Java).